# How to make 2 parted screen with MapView?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to make screen with Google Map.

This screen has 2 parts. First part includes Button TextView and ListView and places on the top of Screen. Second part includes MapView (Google map) and places on the bottom of Screen.

How to make it ?

I've done it. But no luck. It throws this exception :

```
01-07 11:53:12.813: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackagename.uk/com.mypackagename.uk.MyCustomActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:512)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:564)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:617)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:701)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:613)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:309)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1626)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at com.mypackagename.uk.MyCustomActivity.onCreate(*MyCustomActivity.java:457*)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     ... 11 more
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:237)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:499)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     ... 23 more
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You are only allowed to have a single MapView in a MapActivity
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.setupMapView(MapActivity.java:180)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:279)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:254)
01-07 11:53:12.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725):     ... 27 more
```

I've the line of code that throws exception: MyCustomActivity.java:457

This line is: setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

My XML is :

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top|center_vertical">
<com.mypackagename.uk.MyLayout
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/my_row1">
        <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">     
            <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="15px"></TextView>
                <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map_view_on_yardage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="my-api-code">
</com.google.android.maps.MapView>
</com.mypackagename.uk.MyLayout>
```

Comment: You need to look further down in your stack trace to find the exception that triggered the line you have pasted in above. I would recommend that you edit this question and paste in the entire stack trace, not just this one line.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having issue..I did like this...
Creating a layout which can accept two fragments...
..
On the top_fragment place what ever the content that you need...
and on below fragment place the map fragment...

I hope it will be useful to you...

**nested_frag.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:background="#fff2ff" >
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:background="#fff2ff" >
</FrameLayout>
```

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nested_frag, container, false);
    b = getArguments();

    Fragment map = new MapFragment();

    map.setArguments(b);

    FragmentTransaction trans = getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    trans.add(R.id.top_content, new HomeScreen());
    trans.add(R.id.map, map).addToBackStack("somestack").commit();

    return view;
}
```